# Two columns video Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design

I have a site with two columns which are responsive. In each div Element (left and right) is a video. Everything works just fine in Safari and Firefox but not in Chrome. Do you have any ideas for me on how to make it work in Chrome?

https://jsfiddle.net/x1Lx9k5L/1/

HTML:

```
 <div class="left animated fadeInLeft" id="half_left">
            <a href="#"><video id="video-left" loop muted class="bildleft" src="img/video.mp4"></video></a>
```

CSS:

```
.left{
    background-color: #eee;
    width:50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    float:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center center; 
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    right: 50%;
}

.bildleft {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    object-fit: cover;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Just fiddle the code and provide a link for it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x1Lx9k5L/1/

Comment: But in chrome? finish your statement @ManuelS.

Comment: I am sorry. In Chrome the video overlap each other

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers consider white space also as a space:

Even when you use width of both sides as `50%` the whitespace might spoil the party: Therefore try to remove the white space i.e.

```
<div class="left animated fadeInLeft" id="half_left"> The embeded video here </div><div class="right animated fadeInRight" id="half_right">  The embeded video here  </div>
```

In pictures

[image]

Another thing. since you would want the divs to be together. it would be well if you float all the divs to the left even the one in the right: